# Mysql ORDER BY specific value

Tags: mysql

Suppose I have the following query:

```
SELECT id, name FROM table ORDER BY name
```

- 4, Ashley
- 1, Anna
- 2, David
- 3, Zach

How would I throw a particular name to the front of the order and then do the rest of the ordering, something like:

```
SELECT id, name FROM table ORDER BY name='david', name
```

- 1, David
- 4, Ashley
- 1, Anna
- 3, Zach

Answer (score 9):

You are almost exactly there.  You just need `desc`:

```
SELECT id, name
FROM table
ORDER BY (name = 'david') DESC, name;
```

MySQL treats booleans as integers, with true being "1" and false being "0".  So, when it is true, the value is a "1".  To put it first, you need to sort in descending order.